# How can I alter rules action variable?

Tags: 7, rules

I have a custom Rules action, and it returns a value to an action variable.

For it I use code below

```
  return array('array_added' => $item);
```

How can I alter this variable further?

Comment: Try this hook 'hook_rules_action_info_alter' , this may help you